# Fluentbit stop processing after while

Tags: fluent-bit

To push the messages to the Elassandra server, we are utilising the Fluenbit version listed below.

"fluent/fluent-bit" imageName
"1.6.10-debug" imageTag

As long as there are fresh messages in the log file, the system will push them to the Elassandra server, but eventually it will pause and stop processing.
The only workaround we have is to kill the Fluentbit pod, but this only fixes the problem temporarily.

could you please let us know what could be the possible issue and provide some pointers to fix this?

```html
{"index":{"_index":"wso2am-uat-requests-2022.10","_type":"requests","_id":"f1bcb7ad-8b81-d749-e17a-e460218a4f74"}}
{"@timestamp":"2022-10-14T06:53:19.434Z","event":{"date":"2022-10-14 06:53:18","meta_clientType":"{\"correlationID\":\"99de4331-720e-4dd9-959c-6584494fb546\",\"keyType\":\"PRODUCTION\"}","applicationConsumerKey":"rRIFXR2yscFcuZ8cIlWtO1_tYT0a","applicationName":"SRE-PrometheusExporter_FM-MyCEVA","applicationId":"1690","applicationOwner":"svc_fm_sre@service.logistics.corp","apiContext":"/fm/myceva/usermaintenance/1.2.0","apiName":"MyCevaUserMaintenanceAPI","apiVersion":"1.2.0","apiResourcePath":"/usermaintenance/1.2.0/clientSettings?email=harold.boutan@protonmail.com","apiResourceTemplate":"/clientSettings","apiMethod":"GET","apiCreator":"PalliyaliS","apiCreatorTenantDomain":"carbon.super","apiTier":"Bronze","apiHostname":"apim-intgw-uat-west.kus.logistics.corp","username":"svc_fm_sre@service.logistics.corp@carbon.super","userTenantDomain":"carbon.super","userIp":"10.40.69.107","userAgent":"Go-http-client/1.1","requestTimestamp":1665730398703,"throttledOut":false,"responseTime":172,"serviceTime":27,"backendTime":145,"responseCacheHit":false,"responseSize":0,"protocol":"http--1","responseCode":200,"destination":"https://myceva-user-maintenance-stage.kus.logistics.corp/userMaintenance/v1","securityLatency":25,"throttlingLatency":0,"requestMedLat":0,"responseMedLat":0,"backendLatency":145,"otherLatency":0,"gatewayType":"SYNAPSE","label":"Synapse","properties":"{}"}}
{"index":{"_index":"wso2am-uat-requests-2022.10","_type":"requests","_id":"0f609734-607e-6c59-be20-f4918136dbe3"}}
{"@timestamp":"2022-10-14T06:53:19.434Z","event":{"date":"2022-10-14 06:53:18","meta_clientType":"{\"correlationID\":\"90841c12-b0af-466c-bacd-19a689f7cbda\",\"keyType\":\"PRODUCTION\"}","applicationConsumerKey":"qHAj5zfrF6CPfLWWlKb5u07oDz4a","applicationName":"FM-CBD-Backoffice","applicationId":"443","applicationOwner":"svc_backoffice@service.logistics.corp","apiContext":"/fm/myceva/backoffice/1.7.0","apiName":"MyCevaBackofficeAPI","apiVersion":"1.7.0","apiResourcePath":"/backoffice/1.7.0/getClientSettings?client_id=&gluu_user_principal=harold.boutan@protonmail.com","apiResourceTemplate":"/getClientSettings","apiMethod":"GET","apiCreator":"PalliyaliS","apiCreatorTenantDomain":"carbon.super","apiTier":"Bronze","apiHostname":"apim-intgw-uat-west.kus.logistics.corp","username":"svc_backoffice@service.logistics.corp@carbon.super","userTenantDomain":"carbon.super","userIp":"10.40.69.105","userAgent":"Java/11.0.16","requestTimestamp":1665730398814,"throttledOut":false,"responseTime":54,"serviceTime":28,"backendTime":26,"responseCacheHit":false,"responseSize":0,"protocol":"http--1","responseCode":200,"destination":"https://backoffice-stage.kus.logistics.corp/backoffice","securityLatency":27,"throttlingLatency":0,"requestMedLat":0,"responseMedLat":0,"backendLatency":26,"otherLatency":0,"gatewayType":"SYNAPSE","label":"Synapse","properties":"{}"}}
[2022/10/14 06:53:20] [debug] [upstream] KA connection #86 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 is now available
[2022/10/14 06:53:20] [debug] [task] destroy task=0x7fc962c576c0 (task_id=5)
[2022/10/14 06:53:24] [debug] [upstream] KA connection #83 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 is now available
[2022/10/14 06:53:24] [debug] [task] destroy task=0x7fc962c57300 (task_id=0)
[2022/10/14 06:53:24] [debug] [upstream] KA connection #81 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 is now available
[2022/10/14 06:53:24] [debug] [task] destroy task=0x7fc962c57c60 (task_id=8)
[2022/10/14 06:53:25] [debug] [upstream] KA connection #87 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 is now available
[2022/10/14 06:53:25] [debug] [task] destroy task=0x7fc962c57940 (task_id=6)
[2022/10/14 06:53:25] [debug] [upstream] KA connection #82 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 is now available
[2022/10/14 06:53:25] [debug] [task] destroy task=0x7fc962c57440 (task_id=1)
[2022/10/14 06:53:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/alert.log
[2022/10/14 06:53:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] cannot read info from: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/alert.log
[2022/10/14 06:53:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/alert.log'
[2022/10/14 06:53:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.1] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/throttled.log
[2022/10/14 06:53:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.1] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/throttled.log, inode 1099532988751
[2022/10/14 06:53:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.1] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/throttled.log'
[2022/10/14 06:53:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.2] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/faults.log
[2022/10/14 06:53:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.2] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/faults.log, inode 1099532988752
[2022/10/14 06:53:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.2] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/faults.log'
[2022/10/14 06:53:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.3] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/requests.log
[2022/10/14 06:53:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.3] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/requests.log, inode 1099532988750
[2022/10/14 06:53:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.3] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/requests.log'
[2022/10/14 06:53:48] [debug] [upstream] drop keepalive connection #85 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 (keepalive idle timeout)
[2022/10/14 06:53:48] [debug] [upstream] drop keepalive connection #80 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 (keepalive idle timeout)
[2022/10/14 06:53:48] [debug] [upstream] drop keepalive connection #84 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 (keepalive idle timeout)
[2022/10/14 06:53:48] [debug] [upstream] KA connection #85 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 has been disconnected by the remote service
[2022/10/14 06:53:48] [debug] [upstream] KA connection #80 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 has been disconnected by the remote service
[2022/10/14 06:53:48] [debug] [upstream] KA connection #84 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 has been disconnected by the remote service
[2022/10/14 06:53:50] [debug] [upstream] drop keepalive connection #88 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 (keepalive idle timeout)
[2022/10/14 06:53:50] [debug] [upstream] drop keepalive connection #86 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 (keepalive idle timeout)
[2022/10/14 06:53:50] [debug] [upstream] KA connection #88 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 has been disconnected by the remote service
[2022/10/14 06:53:50] [debug] [upstream] KA connection #86 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 has been disconnected by the remote service
[2022/10/14 06:53:54] [debug] [upstream] drop keepalive connection #83 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 (keepalive idle timeout)
[2022/10/14 06:53:54] [debug] [upstream] drop keepalive connection #81 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 (keepalive idle timeout)
[2022/10/14 06:53:54] [debug] [upstream] KA connection #83 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 has been disconnected by the remote service
[2022/10/14 06:53:54] [debug] [upstream] KA connection #81 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 has been disconnected by the remote service
[2022/10/14 06:53:56] [debug] [upstream] drop keepalive connection #87 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 (keepalive idle timeout)
[2022/10/14 06:53:56] [debug] [upstream] drop keepalive connection #82 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 (keepalive idle timeout)
[2022/10/14 06:53:56] [debug] [upstream] KA connection #87 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 has been disconnected by the remote service
[2022/10/14 06:53:56] [debug] [upstream] KA connection #82 to usdcfed-elassandra-kubelb.kus.logistics.corp:9200 has been disconnected by the remote service
[2022/10/14 06:54:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/alert.log
[2022/10/14 06:54:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] cannot read info from: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/alert.log
[2022/10/14 06:54:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/alert.log'
[2022/10/14 06:54:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.3] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/requests.log
[2022/10/14 06:54:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.3] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/requests.log, inode 1099532988750
[2022/10/14 06:54:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.3] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/requests.log'
[2022/10/14 06:54:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.1] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/throttled.log
[2022/10/14 06:54:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.1] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/throttled.log, inode 1099532988751
[2022/10/14 06:54:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.1] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/throttled.log'
[2022/10/14 06:54:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.2] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/faults.log
[2022/10/14 06:54:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.2] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/faults.log, inode 1099532988752
[2022/10/14 06:54:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.2] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/faults.log'
[2022/10/14 06:55:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.1] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/throttled.log
[2022/10/14 06:55:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.1] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/throttled.log, inode 1099532988751
[2022/10/14 06:55:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.1] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/throttled.log'
[2022/10/14 06:55:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/alert.log
[2022/10/14 06:55:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] cannot read info from: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/alert.log
[2022/10/14 06:55:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/alert.log'
[2022/10/14 06:55:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.3] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/requests.log
[2022/10/14 06:55:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.3] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/requests.log, inode 1099532988750
[2022/10/14 06:55:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.3] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/requests.log'
[2022/10/14 06:55:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.2] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/faults.log
[2022/10/14 06:55:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.2] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/faults.log, inode 1099532988752
[2022/10/14 06:55:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.2] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/faults.log'
[2022/10/14 06:56:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.1] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/throttled.log
[2022/10/14 06:56:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.1] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/throttled.log, inode 1099532988751
[2022/10/14 06:56:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.1] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/throttled.log'
[2022/10/14 06:56:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.2] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/faults.log
[2022/10/14 06:56:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.2] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/faults.log, inode 1099532988752
[2022/10/14 06:56:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.2] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/faults.log'
[2022/10/14 06:56:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/alert.log
[2022/10/14 06:56:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] cannot read info from: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/alert.log
[2022/10/14 06:56:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/alert.log'
[2022/10/14 06:56:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.3] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/requests.log
[2022/10/14 06:56:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.3] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/requests.log, inode 1099532988750
[2022/10/14 06:56:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.3] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/requests.log'
[2022/10/14 06:57:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.2] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/faults.log
[2022/10/14 06:57:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.2] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/faults.log, inode 1099532988752
[2022/10/14 06:57:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.2] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/faults.log'
[2022/10/14 06:57:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.1] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/throttled.log
[2022/10/14 06:57:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.1] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/throttled.log, inode 1099532988751
[2022/10/14 06:57:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.1] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/throttled.log'
[2022/10/14 06:57:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/alert.log
[2022/10/14 06:57:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] cannot read info from: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/alert.log
[2022/10/14 06:57:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/alert.log'
[2022/10/14 06:57:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.3] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/requests.log
[2022/10/14 06:57:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.3] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/requests.log, inode 1099532988750
[2022/10/14 06:57:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.3] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/requests.log'
[2022/10/14 06:58:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.2] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/faults.log
[2022/10/14 06:58:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.2] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/faults.log, inode 1099532988752
[2022/10/14 06:58:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.2] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/faults.log'
[2022/10/14 06:58:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.1] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/throttled.log
[2022/10/14 06:58:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.1] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/throttled.log, inode 1099532988751
[2022/10/14 06:58:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.1] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/throttled.log'
[2022/10/14 06:58:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/alert.log
[2022/10/14 06:58:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] cannot read info from: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/alert.log
[2022/10/14 06:58:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/alert.log'
[2022/10/14 06:58:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.3] scanning path /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/requests.log
[2022/10/14 06:58:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.3] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/requests.log, inode 1099532988750
[2022/10/14 06:58:44] [debug] [input:tail:tail.3] 0 new files found on path '/home/fluent/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/events/requests.log'
(⎈ |usdc-east-wso2am-uat:wso2am-uat)➜  apictl
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an old version. Do you see the same behavior with a newer version (1.9 or building from the master branch)?